# OKTA Redirect Not working - React routing

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, react-router, okta

I have written an OKTA enabled React application (OIDC with PKCE).
The application is working fine when I run it locally from node server (npm start).

The moment I put the dist files in Apache, the same code with exactly the same hosted path is not working.

**Details below**

The REDIRECT URI which is working with node server (npm start) is the below.

http://localhost:3000/tmbo/login/callback

Now when I host this in Apache (locally); the same redirect URI fail with Page Not found (there is some routing issues, which I can't figure out).

http://localhost:8080/tmbo/login/callback

Please note that the configuration on the OKTA side is proper. Need some guidance thanks.

**References**

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/implement-grant-type/authcodepkce/main/#next-steps

Comment: Have you checked the apache redirect rules as described [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing)?

Comment: I had placed the .htaccess file alongwith the dist folder contents (at same level as index.html) It didn't work. Get this error:     GET http://localhost:8080/tmbo/login/callback?code=AOw0dAfJ5nLunUPz5psxpU8Pru2jpvSeQTxVxtkZEZ8&state=JVaxZoWpTOOqSkh0oG9HLDJfhFTPkLC4yT352iqXHxMT9scR1oZT2tHzUsHUU5kE 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The below was done to fix the issue.**

1. In the httpd.conf the rewrite module was commented. It was un-commented (remove the # in front)

> LoadModule rewrite_module lib/httpd/modules/mod_rewrite.so

2. In the httpd.conf, under the DirectoryRoot

   AllowOverride None

   was **changed** to

   AllowOverride All
3. The .htaccess file was placed under the virtual directory, contents below.

> .htaccess file contents
>
> ```
> Options -MultiViews
>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
> RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
> ```

**Note**: You can use the below to find the DocumentRoot and ServerRoot.

apachectl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG